# Upgrading Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Datacenter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to upgrade Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise?

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/318248/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-to-datacenter/318261#318261) looks pretty good but keep in mind your question and subject ask about conversion to different versions of Windows (DataCenter or Enterprise).  Which one is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In their [Windows Server 2008 R2 Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563(WS.10).aspx) document, Microsoft indicates the following about cross-edition upgrades:

> Cross-edition upgrades (for example, the Windows Server 2008 Foundation SKU to the Windows Server 2008 Datacenter SKU) are not supported.

However, it looks as though `dism` can be used to upgrade editions.  See this [Technet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2009/10/14/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-without-media.aspx) for more details.  Please note that the blog indicates this upgrade cannot be performed on a Domain Controller.

Display current edition:

```
PS C:\> dism /online /get-currentedition
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Image Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Current edition is:
Current Edition : ServerStandard
The operation completed successfully.
```

Check the available editions:

```
PS C:\> dism /online /get-targeteditions
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Image Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Editions that can be upgraded to:
Target Edition : ServerDataCenter
Target Edition : ServerEnterprise
The operation completed successfully.
```

Upgrade to Enterprise:

```
PS C:\> dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerEnterprise /ProductKey:489J6-VHDMP-X63PK-3K798-CPX3Y
...
```

Comment: This is great for a lab, not so great if you think you'll ever need support

Comment: @JimB This is a supported way to upgrade CALs from Microsoft.  Also here are product keys that may be used if in KMS mode: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793421.aspx

Comment: It may be supported by someone but I suspect most people will prefer Microsoft to support it. I wouldn't want to try to convince Microsoft to support my production issues when you specifically decide not to follow the explicitly spelled out as unsupported, cross edition upgrade.