# Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise Problems

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, xen, xenserver, citrix

A few months ago I setup a Citrix XenApp cluster running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition using the temporary 180 day license key.

Recently the company bought a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise DataCenter license. This means I need to upgrade the Windows edition from Standard to Enterprise.

I attach the disk to the VM and start the upgrade process through XenCenter, it runs through all checks and unpacks all Windows files and seems to create a Windows Setup partition, it then reboots and trys to boot into this partition and I get a blue screen telling me to CHKDSK the hard drive with the following error message:

```
STOP: 0x0000007B
```

As XenApp is already setup and working I really do not want to go down the route of rebuilding this server (as I already had to do this once down to issues with XenApp).

The server did have 8GB of RAM assigned to it, I have tried reducing this down to 2GB's as I read this can cause an issue.

Also I can boot back into the Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard partition without any problems.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get round the urgency by re-arming the license, giving me another 180 day trial..but would be nice to work out why this is happening!

Comment: Are you using the Windows Anytime Upgrade?

Comment: No, I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2 iso attached to the VM as a disc. I did not think Anytime had anything to do with Windows Server?

Comment: So are you logged onto the machine with the media loaded and run the setup from within Windows, or are you booting to the media from start-up?

Comment: Logged in, running the CD, not booting from the disc, but I can try this.

Comment: The correct way to upgrade is by logging in and running the setup. Try the upgrade, then use the CD to get into the setup so you can run the start-up repair. The STOP code you listed refers to inaccessible boot device, running a repair on the boot sector 'might' resolve this.

Comment: I can log into the server fine still, I have run chkdsk against the hard disk and this is fine and reported no problems, the only problem seems to be with the partition created by Windows (Windows Setup Recovery partition) which still does not seem to be reporting any errors unless I boot into it, which you need to do to finish the upgrade.

Comment: Just FYI, [cross-edition upgrades are not support by Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563%28WS.10%29.aspx).  See also: [Upgrading Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Datacenter](http://serverfault.com/questions/318248/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-to-datacenter).

Comment: It says here it is supported: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563%28WS.10%29.aspx. Ignore that, I should read it more carefully, 2003 - 2008R2 does work but not cross-edition. But I will try using dsim now.

Comment: @jscott - Do you want to put that as an answer, running the dsim commands worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jscott pointed out in the comments:

[Upgrading Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Datacenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/318248/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-to-datacenter)

Answers this question.